# EWS Managed API - Ignore Meeting Requests

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Using EWS API to retrieve unread messages from mailbox using code below.  It is retrieving meeting requests (or invites) also.  Is there a way to ignore these type of emails?

```
//search filter to get unread email
var searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));

//count of unread emails to retrieve
var view = new ItemView(50) { PropertySet = new PropertySet(PropertySet.IdOnly) };

//properties to return in the result set
var propertySet = new PropertySet {
    ItemSchema.Subject,
    ItemSchema.Body,
    ItemSchema.HasAttachments,
    ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived };

//order the search results by the DateTimeReceived in asc order
view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);

//set the traversal to shallow - shallow is the default option other options are Associated and SoftDeleted
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;

do {
    //get emails from Inbox using search filter, view and retrieve properties defined above
    findResults = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);
    if (findResults.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    view.Offset += findResults.Items.Count;
} while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meeting requests will have a different ItemClass so you can either just filter them at the client side (which is what I would do) or create a SearchFilter to just return Items with an ItemClass of IPF.Note (however you may miss some items this way).

Comment: Can you provide an example?  How would I filter at the client side?

Comment: All you need to do is add ItemSchema.ItemClass to the property set and then in your //do stuff part look at the value of the ItemClass property to determine what type of item your dealing with. The EWS Managed API also returns typed items so why don't you just check the Item type eg if(Item is EmailMessage) etc (Meeting invitations will be MeetingRequest). You should try it yourself first before asking people to write code for you, this is they way you learn even if what you write doesn't work.